# How to properly power my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: power

What's my best alternative to power my raspberry? Can I plug it into a USB socket in my main PC? Can I plug it in in a socket like I was charging a phone?

Comment: The best alternative is relative, but what about the official power supply? A Pi 4 might work from a USB 3 port. A USB 2 port and phone charger may have issues reliably powering a Pi 4.

Comment: Buy the official power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/?resellerType=home